# Unable to expand numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array containing information about images. It contains information about 21495 images in an array named 'shuffled'.

```
np.shape(shuffled) = (21495, 1)
np.shape(shuffled[0]) = (1,)
np.shape(shuffled[0][0]) = (128, 128, 3) # (These are the image dimensions, with 3 channels of RGB)
```

How do I convert this array to an array of shape (21495, 128, 128, 3) to feed to my model?

Comment: Can you post the array `.dtypes`?

Comment: Are you sure all images have the same shape?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways that I can think of:

One is using the `vstack()` fucntion of numpy, but it gets quite slow overtime when the size of array starts to increase.

Another way (which I use) is to take an empty list and keep appending the images array to that list using `.append()`, then finally convert that list to a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
np.stack(shuffled[:,0])
```

`stack`, a form of `concatenate`, joins a list (or array) of arrays on a new initial dimension.  We need to get get rid of the size 1 dimension first.

```
In [23]: arr = np.empty((4,1),object)                                           
In [24]: for i in range(4): arr[i,0] = np.arange(i,i+6).reshape(2,3)            
In [25]: arr                                                                    
Out[25]: 
array([[array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])],
       [array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])],
       [array([[2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7]])],
       [array([[3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])]], dtype=object)
In [26]: arr.shape                                                              
Out[26]: (4, 1)
In [27]: arr[0,0].shape                                                         
Out[27]: (2, 3)
In [28]: np.stack(arr[:,0])                                                     
Out[28]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]],

       [[2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7]],

       [[3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]]])
In [29]: _.shape                                                                
Out[29]: (4, 2, 3)
```

But beware, if the subarrays differ in shape, say one or two is b/w rather than 3 channel, this won't work.